# Terminating app, reason: 'Storyboard () doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'listview'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

I don't know the reason for this error.

Source code:

```
let roomsbedsViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "listview")

self.present(roomsbedsViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Error showing in:

```
let roomsbedsViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "listview")
```

Error Log:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard () doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'listview''
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107eddb0b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010c362141 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   UIKit                               0x000000010aa2193f -[UIStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController] + 0
    3   DropInn                             0x0000000105688a48 _TFC7DropInn26PropertyTypeViewController7backBtnfCSo8UIButtonT_ + 1704
    4   DropInn                             0x0000000105688f4a _TToFC7DropInn26PropertyTypeViewController7backBtnfCSo8UIButtonT_ + 58
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010a263d22 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010a3e825c -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010a3e8577 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 450
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010a3e74b2 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 618
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010a2d149a -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2707
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010a2d2bb0 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4114
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010a27f7b0 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 352
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010aa62adc __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 2926
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010aa5aa3a __handleEventQueue + 1122
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107e83c01 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107e690cf __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 527
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107e685ff __CFRunLoopRun + 911
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107e68016 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 406
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x000000011034ea24 GSEventRunModal + 62
    19  UIKit                               0x000000010a2620d4 UIApplicationMain + 159
    20  DropInn                             0x0000000105345847 main + 55
    21  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010da7365d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Storyboard screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Are you having multiple srotyboard in your app ? Also try once rewriting the Storyboard ID so remove it once and set it again.

Comment: I'm already tried this method(Rename my storyboard ID). But still i faced this Error

Comment: Are you having multiple stortyboard in your app ?

Comment: I cleaned my project before run.

Comment: No i just having single storyboard

Answer (score 4):

Please check on **use Storyboard ID**.......

When you check on **use Storyboard ID**, The Textfield of  **Registration ID** will be highlighted with your Storyboard ID .....

In your example ...
The textfield of registration ID will be highlighted with **listview**

[image]

Hope your doubt is clear

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

If you are using multiple storyboards then try this:

```
let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "listView")
```

Use **UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)** instead of self.storyboard

Reason :
If you are calling self.storyboard from a view controller that is on another storyboard file, it will give reference to that particular storyboard; not the main storyboard.

Answer (score -2):

i got the same problem after i cope the storybord to my project

and i fix it by clicking stroybord then clicking file inspector and i select my target membership.